# Cookies vs Service for storing cart_id. Which is better Practice?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, e-commerce

Software Stack:

AngularJS

Rails

**Option A**:

When a user GETS "/", the server creates a cart in the db and writes the id to a cookie.  Angular reads the id from the cookie and uses it in the cart resource.

When a cart gets purchased, the server will have to issue a new cart_id.

**Option B**:

Angular GETS "/cart" when it needs a cart_id, the server checks the session to see if it made a cart yet. If not, then it creates one, stores it in the session, and replies with the id.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer option B for a couple of reasons, 1) why create the cart when simply navigating to '/' and not on demand?  2) Not a huge fan of cookies.